# swift combine recursively call the api for maximum of 3 times based on value received in receiveCompleation block

Tags: swift, combine

I would like to call an api recursively for max of 3 times if i dont receive a expectedvalue in .sink receiveValue block. I have found examples to retry based on error but i am not sure hou to retry after i get a successful response from api, i can provide more details if the code is unclear.

```
struct DetailModel {
    var status: String
}

func details(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<DetailModel, NetworkCommunicationError> {
    let getDetailsRequest = NetworkRequest(url: url,
                                           queryType: .path,
                                           responseDataType: .json,
                                           isProprietary: true,
                                           useJsonSerialization: true)
    return network.handleRequest(request: getDetailsRequest)
}

func getDetialsById(url: URL) {
    self.responseModel = nil
    
    self.service.details(url: url)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink( { (compleation) in
            if case let.failure(error) = completion {
                self.handleErrorCase(error)
            }
        } receiveValue: { (value) in
            self.responseModel = value
            if value.status != "Paid" {
                self.showConfirmDetails = false
                /*
                 Retry the same call self.service.details for 2 more times
                 with the delay of 5 seconds to check if i can get the value.status ==
                 Paid on the third try even if i dont get value.status == Paid status 
                 i will make
                 self.showConfirmDetails = true
                 and proceed with the status i have received
                */
            } else {
                self.showConfirmDetails = true
            }
        }).store(in: &self.cancellebles)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the playground below has something like you're looking for:

I replaced the network request for a `Future` that just returns a value.  The value it returns is determined by a global variable `failureCount`.  That just lets you decide how many times the network request will fail if it's called many times in a row.

The pipeline uses a `retry` operator.  That operator will retry the publisher preceding it the number of times you ask.  In this case you wanted the request to run once, then retry twice if it didn't return "Paid" (so it runs three times in total).

The success or failure of the request is determined by 1) whether the request runs into a network error and 2) if the subject of the request was paid.  The `Deferred` publisher combines the network request and a `tryMap` that will either succeed, or generate a special `RetryError` for unpaid results.

In the sink you could get one of three things.  A successful result, a `RetryError` or some other error (probably a Network Error).  The completion and value callbacks show how to distinguish each case.

To play with it, at the bottom, set `failureCount` to tell the system how many times you want the network request to return something other than Paid and you can exercise the pipeline.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

struct DetailModel {
  var status: String
}

var failureCount = 3;

func details() -> AnyPublisher<DetailModel,Error> {
  Future<DetailModel, Error> { promise in
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now().advanced(by: .seconds(1))) {
      print("network request completed")

      if 0 == failureCount {
        promise(.success(DetailModel(status: "Paid")))
      } else {
        failureCount -= 1;
        promise(.success(DetailModel(status: "Cheapskate!")))
      }
    }
  }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


var showConfirmDetails = true;
enum RetryError: Error {
  case tryAgain(DetailModel)
}

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
func getDetailsById() {
  Deferred { () -> AnyPublisher<DetailModel,Error> in
    details()
      .tryMap { detail in
        print("Network request returned \(detail.status)")

        if "Paid" == detail.status {
          return detail
        } else {
          print("Didn't get paid")
          throw RetryError.tryAgain(detail)
        }
      }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
  .retry(2)
  .sink { result in
    switch(result) {
    case .finished:
      // All done!
      break;

    case .failure(let error):
      switch error {
      case RetryError.tryAgain(let detail):
        print("Got a detail after three tries \(detail)")
      default:
        print("Some other error occurred. \(error))")
      }
    }
  } receiveValue: { detail in
    print("Got a paid response.")
  }
  .store(in: &subscriptions)
}

failureCount = 2
getDetailsById()
```